# Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04 gets "you do not have proper permissions" when downloading a file to an NFS mount

Tags: 20.04, permissions, firefox, nfs, sssd

I'm running a number of Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop VMs at work, and each of them is having an issue with *only* Firefox when a user tries to download a file.

So, some context first on how our Ubuntu VMs are configured.

### VM Configuration

The way we have things set up is that a user initiates an RDP session to the VM. They authenticate through an `sssd` daemon that sends the provided credentials via LDAP to our Active Directory domains.
AD then returns all of the user information so that `sssd` can start their session with the appropriate UID, GID, Home directory, and whatnot. Below is an example of the info AD would return to `sssd`.

```
root@server:~# getent passwd pwalker
pwalker:*:123456:40:pwalker:/u/pwalker:/bin/bash
```

We have configured a non-standard home directory on every user's AD profile so that when a user logs in to an Ubuntu VM, the `autofs` daemon can automatically mount a network drive folder as the user's home direcory.
It's a convenient way to keep the VM's storage footprint small while giving users an easy way to transfer files from one Ubuntu VM to another.
Below is the configuration of `autofs`.

```
root@server:~# cat /etc/auto.master
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d
/u      /etc/auto_home
```

```
root@server:~# cat /etc/auto_home 
* -rw,intr,nosuid,soft,proto=tcp    sannfs:/ifs/userhome/&
```

Here's some of the mount information, in case the root cause has to do with what options were used.

```
sannfs:/ifs/userhome/pwalker on /u/pwalker type nfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=524288,namlen=255,soft,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,mountvers=3,mountport=300,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

And here's a snapshot of my user's mounted home directory when I connect to a VM.

```
pwalker@server:~$ pwd
/u/pwalker
pwalker@server:~$ ls -la
total 1320
drwxrwxrwx 20 pwalker standard   854 Mar 16 07:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root         0 Mar 16 09:29 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pwalker standard    21 Mar 15 16:51 .bash_aliases
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pwalker standard  1423 Mar 16 08:05 .bash_history
drwxrwxrwx 18 pwalker standard   678 Mar 16 08:12 .cache
drwxrwxrwx 15 pwalker standard   443 Mar 16 08:12 .config
drwxrwxrwx  2 pwalker standard     0 Mar  1 10:58 Desktop
drwxrwxrwx  2 pwalker standard     0 Mar 16 08:14 Documents
drwxrwxrwx  2 pwalker standard    25 Mar 16 09:29 Downloads
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pwalker standard    16 Mar  1 14:33 .esd_auth
drwxrwxrwx  3 pwalker standard    93 Mar 16 08:13 .gnupg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pwalker standard   322 Mar 15 16:27 .ICEauthority
drwxrwxrwx  3 pwalker standard    23 Mar  1 10:58 .local
drwxrwxrwx  4 pwalker standard    53 Mar 15 16:52 .mozilla
drwxrwxrwx  2 pwalker standard     0 Mar  1 10:58 Music
drwxrwxrwx  2 pwalker standard     0 Mar  1 10:58 Pictures
drwxrwxrwx  3 pwalker standard    23 Mar 15 16:27 .pki
drwxrwxrwx  2 pwalker standard     0 Mar  1 10:58 Public
drwxrwxrwx  2 pwalker standard     0 Mar 10 14:01 .ssh
drwxrwxrwx  2 pwalker standard     0 Mar  1 10:58 Templates
drwxrwxrwx  2 pwalker standard     0 Mar  1 10:58 Videos
drwxrwxrwx  2 pwalker standard    67 Mar 15 16:27 .vnc
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pwalker standard   352 Mar 16 07:35 .Xauthority
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pwalker standard 18835 Mar 10 14:02 .xorgxrdp.12.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pwalker standard  4266 Mar 16 07:35 .xsession-errors
```

### Observed Functionality

When connected to the VM, I can download files directly to my mounted home directory using `wget` in a terminal.

I installed Google Chrome and can download files without issue, saving the files directly to my mounted home directory.

I can directly save images using the "right-click, save-image-as" functionality of Firefox.

Using test files from https://filesamples.com, I cannot save links to files using the "right-click, save-link-as" functionality of Firefox.
I also cannot save files by clicking the provided "download" buttons.

The error message I consistently receive is

> The file could not be saved because you do not have the proper permissions. Choose another save directory.

If I select another directory in the mounted home directory, I receive the same error message.

If I select a directory that is local to the VM (eg. `/tmp`), the file is successfully downloaded.

Using the `about:memory` Firefox window, I found the main Process ID to confirm that Firefox is running as my user/group (by checking the content of `cat /proc/###/status`). I confirmed that it was.

### Question Time

- Is there a debugger for Firefox that would provide some more useful context?
- Is there some issue with Firefox running locally on the VM when it tries to save a file directly to the network drive?
- Are there other permissions/settings somewhere that I should check?

Comment: One suggestion from a coworker was to check the ACLs on the directory in the mounted home folder that I was trying to save to. No luck. As far as I could tell, no special permissions were being applied to the directory.

Comment: you're probably just using the snap installation of firefox vs the apt installation. which can be confirmed with `snap list`

Comment: If memory serves, Firefox doesn't specifically remember that you are saving data to `~/Downloads` as a path, but as a reference. If the `inode` references are different when the NFS location is mounted, then Firefox will be trying to save to a location that does not exist. One way to test this would be to change your download settings in Firefox to another directory (temporarily) to see if a download completes 

Comment: @WU-TANG, I checked `snap list` and confirmed that firefox was not installed using that package manager. Firefox was installed with `apt`.

Comment: @matigo I had thought it might be something like that as well. I change the downloading settings to "Always ask where to save files", and selecting any directory (ie. Desktop, Documents, Downloads, etc.) in my "mounted home" still failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up not being with Ubuntu or Firefox (per se), which I guess could have been assumed from the symptoms.

The solution was to resolve some permissions problems writing to *Isilon* and *GPS* shares over NFS. The storage admin had to **adjust some Windows ACLs** (since that's how our team controls read/write permissions for users on the shares) and add the `Delete subfolders and files` special permission to the ACLs. This permissions equates to the `Delete Child` permission in *NFSv4*, which is apparently what Firefox needed.

The admin passed along that he had also observed a similar "ACL permissions" issue with:

- CentOS 8: FTP protocol
- CentOS 8: Virtual python environments (virtualenv)

Hopefully this helps direct someone else towards a solution with their problem. *Keep the heid!*